# Javamail - Pick up the email as soon as it arrives

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I'm using **Javamail** to get some messages from my IMAP email account. It works well but, sometimes the email doesn't arrive at same time of server.

How can I work around of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can monitor a folder like this

from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getName--)

```
Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
folder.addMessageCountListener(new MessageCountAdapter() {
    public void messagesAdded(MessageCountEvent ev) {
        Folder folder = (Folder)ev.getSource();
        Message[] msgs = ev.getMessages();
        System.out.println("Folder: " + folder +
            " got " + msgs.length + " new messages");
        try {
            // process new messages
            idleManager.watch(folder); // keep watching for new messages
        } catch (MessagingException mex) {
            // handle exception related to the Folder
        }
    }
});
idleManager.watch(folder);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're at the mercy of the server and how soon it notifies the client of new messages.

Note also that if you're idle for 30 minutes (typically), the server will close your connection and you'll need to reconnect.  If you want to keep the connection open, you should periodically do something such as folder.getMessageCount(), which will break you out of the IMAP IDLE state and tell the server that you're still using the connection, resetting the idle timeout.

And of course since this is a network, the connection can break for lots of other reasons that you can't prevent, so you always need to be prepared to handle a broken connection.

Comment: Great placement Bill. This information will be very useful to me during the course of my project. Thank you very much.